# (Lua) Condition statements not behaving as expected

Tags: lua

My math teacher has an extra credit halloween problem that goes like this:

each letter represents a digit 2-9, and you need the following problem to work:

trick + or = treat

I decided I want to find ALL possible solutions to the problem (To impress him) so I decide to write a computer program that would tell me the all the answers. Here is my following code:

> local function checkAdd()
>
> local trick =k+(10*c)+(100*i)+(1000*r)+(10000*t)  local _or =r+(10*o)
>     local treat = t+(10*a)+(100*e)+(1000*r)+(10000*t)   if trick + _or ==
>   treat then        print(trick)        print("   ".._or)       print(treat)
>                 print(t)        print(r)        print(i)        print(c)        print(k)        print(o)        print(e)        print(a)    end     --print("end")
>     timer.performWithDelay(1,newNumbers) end local function
>   checkNumbers8()   if t or r or i or c or k or o or e or a == "9" then
>         checkAdd()  else        newNumbers()    end end
>
> local function checkNumbers7()    if t or r or i or c or k or o or e or
>   a == "8" then         checkNumbers8()     else        newNumbers()    end end
>
> local function checkNumbers6()    if t or r or i or c or k or o or e or
>   a == "7" then         checkNumbers7()     else        newNumbers()    end end
>
> local function checkNumbers5()    if t or r or i or c or k or o or e or
>   a == "6" then         checkNumbers6()     else        newNumbers()    end end
>
> local function checkNumbers4()    if t or r or i or c or k or o or e or
>   a == "5" then         checkNumbers5()     else        newNumbers()    end end
>
> local function checkNumbers3()    if t or r or i or c or k or o or e or
>   a == "4" then         checkNumbers4()     else        newNumbers()    end end
>
> local function checkNumbers2()    if t or r or i or c or k or o or e or
>   a == "3" then         checkNumbers3()     else        newNumbers()    end end
>
> local function checkNumbers()     if t or r or i or c or k or o or e or a
>   == "2" then       checkNumbers2()     else        newNumbers()
>             end end
>
> function newNumbers()     t = mRandom(2,9)    r = mRandom(2,9)    i =
>   mRandom(2,9)  c = mRandom(2,9)    k = mRandom(2,9)    o = mRandom(2,9)    e
>   = mRandom(2,9)    a = mRandom(2,9)    checkNumbers() end
>
> newNumbers()

*Please note that on in the function checkAdd I call the function timer.performwithdelay ( waits 1 milisecond before calling the function). This is because if I run this code just regularly without the function call, I get a stack overflow error. So i put my code into a framework I use for app developement that had the timer.performwithdelay call, and I implemented that into my code so the computer won't be so overwhelmed and cause an overflow error.

I get the following print statements:

```
97552
27
97579
9
7
5
5
2
2
5
7
```

and:

```
49325
59
49384
4
9
3
2
5
5
3
8
```

I am getting some letters equaling the same as other letters! and not all numbers 2-9 are used! What is wrong with my code? I test to see if every number 2-9 is used

Comment: Have some indentation please: [edit]

Comment: Indeed. Post the code again and use code sample formatting **not** quote formatting.

Comment: stackoverflow screws up my text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two main issues. I don't see the function `mRandom`, but I assume it returns a *number* and you are comparing it with a *string*. Number 2 is not the same as string '2', so `2 == '2'` returns `false`.

The second issue is that (it seems) you are trying to compare if either of variables has a specific value, but you can't do `if a or b == 2 then` meaning: execute if either `a` or `b` equals 2. For that you need to write `if a == 2 or b == 2`. What you have is evaluated as: if `a` is evaluated as `true` (which is when it's not `nil` or `false`) or `b` equals 2.